# Does my Xbox 360 Premium, purchased in December 2007, support 3D?

Tags: xbox-360, stereo-3d

I purchased my Xbox Premium in December 2007. According to wikipedia:

> In July 2007, this version of the Xbox 360 began appearing with the Zephyr motherboard (the motherboard used in the Elite) which features HDMI 1.2 output and an improved GPU heatsink.

AFAIK, 3D requires HDMI 1.4, so can I get my Xbox to work with 3D? I currently only have component cables for it, and I don't find it worthwhile to purchase an HDMI adapter if it's not going to work anyway.

Comment: Does you're tv support 3d? otherwise i guess it should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is YES if your Xbox has a HDMI connection (and you use it). Get the latest dashboard update and connect to your 3DTV using a HDMI cable (cheap ones are ok if they're less than 6 foot, else get one that says "high speed").

The previous answer is not technically correct but it's close enough (1280x1470 3D framebuffer requires *the same* bandwidth as 1080p/60Hz, as too does 3D Blu-ray at 1080p/24Hz, not 48fps, and it needs more than a custom resolution for full 3D compatibility).

Plenty of games listed here:
http://www.3dtested.com/3d-xbox-360-games-list/

Comment: I assume that this is correct. However, it appears that I have bought an older XBox model at the time of purchase, because mine does not have an HDMI output. Alas, no 3D for me - I was using the using a component video cable, which can't handle 3D :(

Comment: Only a couple of recent games support HDMI 1.4 3D on the 360. All the previous games uses one of the half resolution modes like "side by side" or "top bottom" and some of these games will let you do it over a component connection (and you then put your TV manually into that 3D mode) though there will be slightly more eye strain as the signal isn't lossless and will introduce slight differences to each eye.

Answer (score 0):

It appears, that yes, your console will support it.

> So how is HDMI 1.4 output possible on older consoles? It turns out
>   that the new standard is rather conservative. A 1280x1470 framebuffer
>   actually requires less bandwidth than native 1080p - and both Xbox 360
>   and PlayStation 3 have supported that for ages. Even 3D Blu-Ray movies
>   only run at with the equivalent bandwidth of 1080p at 48 frames per
>   second - well below the 1920x1200/60Hz max of the interface. So HDMI
>   1.4 support on an HDMI 1.2 console boils down to making the hardware output a custom resolution and nothing more.

Source: [HDMI 1.4 stereo 3D arrives on Xbox 360](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/digitalfoundry-hdmi-3d-on-xbox-360)